# How to report abuse to GoDaddy

Tags: godaddy

Let's say that a website posted a picture of me, without my consent, and I want it to be removed (it's something private, could compromise my career if it's seen by someone that shouldn't). I sent them an email asking nicely that they should remove it, but they didn't respond and the picture is still there.

Using 'Whois' I found that the website is hosted by GoDaddy. Is there a way (an email address, for ex.) to report to GoDaddy that one of the sites they're hosting does something illegal and to force them to remove the photo? I searched the site and found nothing about such a thing.

Comment: I'd give them a call (there's a sales & support number on their main page.)  That might work better than e-mail.  Also keep in mind that if whoever owns the web site is "really" after you, they could upload it just about anywhere else - hell, if it's actually an innocent posting and they get pissed because you send the host after them, that could very well trigger that.  Or not.  Just thinking out loud in a paranoid kind of way... :) Good luck.

Comment: Is the picture yours? Then give a call to GoDaddy's DMCA line. If the picture is of you without consent, general abuse (though in courts it's the photography laws).

Comment: I had a similar experience where someone posted pics of my kids on a registered hate group site which used GoDaddy's domain registration. I contacted GoDaddy because I wanted to send my request in email for my records. The email is abuse@godaddy.com

Answer (score 3):

Do a DMCA takedown request.  This usually works as long as you can prove the photo is of you.

Comment: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better" taken from [How do I write a good answer?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

In the whois there should be an "abuse" address. Write there.

That said... While it might be your right to want that picture removed, I think you are too paranoid about "compromising your career". Your employers should not care about whatever you do in your spare time: they should only care about if you actually manage to do your job or not. If someone messes up with your life, it's not someone you want to work for anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can't really force anyone to remove a picture of you, unless you have damn good lawyers, and enough money to pay them, but you can pester the crap out of the admins until they tell you to take a hike, or just yank it themselves.

Generally complaint addresses are of the format <abuse [at] godaddy.com>, <support [at] godaddy.com> or something along those lines.

Also try https://supportcenter.godaddy.com/Abuse/SpamReport.aspx and set the support type to Misc. That might get you some attention.